# How to pass/delete array params in HTTP Params with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, url, http-parameters

I have an Array of statuses objects. Every status has a name, and a boolean set at false by default.

It represent checkbox in a form with filters, when a checkbox is checked bool is set at true :

```
const filters.statuses = [
   { 
     name: "pending", 
     value: false
   }, 
   { 
     name: "done", 
     value: false
   }, 
];
```

I am using Angular HTTP Params to pass params at the URL.

```
        filters.statuses.forEach((status) => {
          if (status.value) {
            this.urlParams = this.urlParams.append('statuses[]', status.name);
          }
        });
```

Url params looks like when a status is checked :
**&statuses%5B%5D=pending**

My problem is when I want to unchecked.
I know HTTP Params is Immutable, so, I'm trying to delete the param when checkbox is unchecked, so set to false :

```
...else {
this.urlParams = this.urlParams.delete('statuses');
}
```

But, it not works, URL doesn't change.
And if I re-check to true after that, the URL looks like :

**&statuses%5B%5D=pending&statuses%5B%5D=pending**

How can I delete params, if the status value is false, and keep others statuses in URL ?
Project on Angular 10.

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE : It works to delete, my param name was not good :

```
else {
       this.urlParams = this.urlParams.delete('statuses[]', status.name);
     }
```

But, my other problem, it's when I check 2 or more checkbox, the append function write on URL : **&statuses%5B%5D=pending&statuses%5B%5D=pending&statuses%5B%5D=done**

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared an example to try to answer your question (If I understand this right way).

You can change the checkboxes state or the URL to play with it. Also, I added helper buttons, which will navigate you to different cases (by changing the URL).

Here is the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-cffkwu?file=app/views/home/home.component.ts

There are some parts. We will talk about HomeComponent.

1. You have ngFor which displays statuses, I handled state using ngModel (you can choose whatever you want).
2. You have a subscription to the `activatedRoute.queryParams` observable, this is how you get params and set up checkboxes (the model of the checkboxes)
3. You have the `ngModelChange` handler, this is how you change the route according to the checkboxes state

Let's focus on 2 & 3 items.

The second one. Rendering the correct state according to the route query params. Here is the code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      const statusesFromParams = params?.statuses || [];

      this.statuses = this.statuses.map((status) => {
        if (statusesFromParams.includes(status.name)) {
          return {
            name: status.name,
            active: true,
          };
        }

        return {
          name: status.name,
          active: false,
        };
      });
    });
  }
```

Here I parse the `statuses` queryParam and I set up the statuses model. I decide which is active and which is not here.

The third one. You need to update the URL according to the checkboxes state. Here is the code:

```
// HTML
<ng-container *ngFor="let status of statuses">
  {{ status.name}} <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="status.active" (ngModelChange)="onInputChange()" /> <br />
</ng-container>

// TypeScript
onInputChange() {
    this.router.navigate(['./'], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
      queryParams: {
        statuses: this.statuses
          .filter((status) => status.active)
          .map((status) => status.name),
      },
    });
  }
```

Here you have the ngModelChange handler. When any checkbox is checked/unchecked this handler is invoked. In the handler, I use the `navigate` method of the Router to change the URL. I collect actual checkboxes state and build the query parameters for the navigation event.

So, now you have a binding of the checkboxes state to the URL and vice versa. Hope this helps.